# How to define a closure that accepts an arbitrary data element and produces "some" View?

Tags: swiftui

I am building a custom view that displays a collection of strings, but would like to extend it to accept a closure that will render each one of these strings differently, potentially not as a `Text` view.  For example, this is my original code:

```
struct MyCollectionView : View {
  var data : [String]
  var body : some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { string in
        Text(string) // <- will try to invoke the closure here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now I would like to inject a "renderer" closure that will accept a string and produce a view, something like this:

```
struct MyCollectionView : View {
  typealias CellRenderer = (String)->View
  var cellRenderer : CellRenderer = { string in // compiler error on CellRenderer: "Protocol 'View' 
    // can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"
    Text(string)
  } // default implementation
  var data : [String]
  var body : some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { string in
        self.cellRenderer(string) // <- trying to invoke the cell renderer
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I declare this kind of closure?  Perhaps it shouldn't be a closure but an object that will produce `some View` given a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of possible approaches. Works with Xcode 11.2, iOS 13.2.

```
struct MyCollectionView<Data, Cell>: View where Data: Hashable, Cell: View {
    typealias CellRenderer = (Data) -> Cell
    var data : [Data]
    var cellRenderer : CellRenderer


    init(_ data: [Data], @ViewBuilder cellRenderer: @escaping CellRenderer) {
        self.data = data
        self.cellRenderer = cellRenderer
    }

    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { value in
                self.cellRenderer(value)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MyCollectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyCollectionView(["one", "two"]) { value in
            Text(value)
        }
    }
}
```